# Get angular application html page with module elements

Tags: node.js, angularjs, node-modules

I am trying to get html element of an angular app but when I am using request module, I am only getting the source which has module tag but not the actual rendered html page.

Is there any way I can get rendered html page with all elements rendered in request response.

```
var request = require ("request")

request (
  { uri: "http://www.myangular-app.com"},
    function (error, response, body){
               console.log(body);  // ---> Receiving source only, not the rendered elements of module.
 });
```

Comment: If you don't do server rendering it's normal. The angularjs application has to be executed in a browser.

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to get the rendered page content through the request or any other node module.

Comment: you can use selenium with chrome-driver. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver .

Comment: Okay yes, it seems to be the only option.